# Firebase Analytics is not working on iOs (Dart/Flutter)

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, dart

I use dart/flutter in my application and successfully connected firebase cloud to both Android and iOs versions of the App. Data from Firebase Cloud is shown on both platforms correctly. But there is no information about iOs users in Analytics. Analytics of the Android version is shown correctly. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Have you found the issue? I have the same behavior on my side.

Comment: Yes. Add dependence firebase_analytics: ^5.0.2

Comment: @Alexander So just adding the dependence solved the issue?